# Сумма элементов матрицы над главной диагональю

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Необходимо вычислить сумму элементов матрицы A[N,N], находящихся над главной диагональю.

Мой код:

```
import random
s=0
i=0
k=1
N=int(input())
A=[[random.randrange(10) for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
for k in range(N):
    while i<N:
        while k<N:
            s+=A[i][k]
            k+=1
        i+=1
print(s)
```

Но, неверный вывод программа выдает. Подскажите как поступить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for row in range(N):
    for col in range(row + 1, N):
         s+=A[row][col]
```